Calculate CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM by CameraCharacteristics data
I have the problem with converting forwardMatrix (-es) to sRGB (Rec.709) Linear (without gamma correction) colorspace.
We have such information available:
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_REFERENCE_ILLUMINANT1
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_REFERENCE_ILLUMINANT2
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_FORWARD_MATRIX1
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_FORWARD_MATRIX2
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM1
CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM2
CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS

How to get a normal image using this information? What actions and in what order should be performed?
I would be grateful for any tips. I read the entire Internet and did not find any documentation on how to do this correctly in Android.
At the moment I have an algorithm that does not work:
1. rgbmatrix = [
      [COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS.getRed(),0,0],
      [0,1,0], //Green always is 1
      [0,0,COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS.getBlue()]
   ]

2. rgbcalibmatrix = rgbmatrix 
      * lerp(SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM1, SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM2)

3. rgbcalibforwardmatrix = rgbcalibmatrix 
      * lerp(SENSOR_FORWARD_MATRIX1, SENSOR_FORWARD_MATRIX2)

4. result = rgbcalibforwardmatrix * XYZ_to_sRGBLinearD65

XYZ_to_sRGBLinearD65 is correct, checked a lot of times. Calibration and Forward matrixes are present in RAW files that developed correctly. I want to find the error why my blue channel has a lot of red.
Instead of the matrix that the device creates in camera auto mode
ColorSpaceTransform(
    [1299/1000, -206/1000, -93/1000], 
    [-88/1000, 1136/1000, -48/1000], 
    [-19/1000, -163/1000, 1182/1000]
)

I get something completely different
ColorSpaceTransform(
    [2955/1000, -959/1000, -226/1000], 
    [-433/1000, 1554/1000, -130/1000], 
    [889/1000, -2000/1000, 2409/1000]
)

